# Attempt to assign property of a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, view, model

i want to save data in to table with these code

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="Name"> City Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city_name">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CityController.php**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

    $options = array();

    $options->city_name=$request->get('city_name');

    $attributes  =array('city_name');


    $table = 'cities';
    (new City())->store($table,$attributes,$options);
    return redirect('cities')->with('success','Information has been  inserted');
}
```

my model is 
**City.php**

```
  public function store($table,$attributes,$options)
{
    (new Root())->store($table,$attributes,$options);
}
```

with root model **Root.php**

```
    public function store($table ,$attributes, $options)  {

    $value = array();

    foreach($attributes as $key=>$data)
    {
        $value[$data] = $options[$key];
    }
    DB::table($table)->insert($value);
}
```

but when i push the submit button in create view give me the

ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Attempt to assign property 'city_name' of non-object

how can i solve this?

Comment: `$options = array(); $options->city_name`. You're initializing `$options` as an array and then trying to use it as an object.

Comment: Do you mean `$options = new stdClass;`?

Comment: This means that model doesn't have scope

Comment: how can i put scope on model
https://stackoverflow.com/users/5212418/vasim-shaikh

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an array with the object accessor. In your controller it should be:

```
$options = array();

$options['city_name'] = $request->get('city_name');

$attributes = array('city_name');
```

Comment: i use this way but i got this error that redirect me to root model  ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined offset: 0